# Auto login to a website + getting cookie parameters (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, autologin

Is it possible to create auto login to a website using C#? For example, I want to authenticate from server with external website and get some params from cookies. Maybe there are exist special libraries for this purpose?

Comment: The answer is yes, but to get any better answer you need to provide details. Otherwise likely this question will be closed.

Comment: I have an ASP .NET server application. I need to send request with authorization details to another site (which is not .NET driven), make authentication and get information which the cookies for this site provide.

Answer (score 0):

What you intend to do if possible, and there are several ways you could try to use **membership provider** that lets you easily user creation, management, and change profiles, including autoload status, to enter the site.
I hope you need this information.

Comment: An if the site, to which I need to login is not created using .NET, is it still possible to use membership providers?